# Gaussian mixture model - get the contour of given probability value : Matlab

Tags: matlab, mixture-model, gmm

I need to identify the 99% probability contour of a GMM fitted to data. Following this example, I'd like to be able to specify which contours to plot, and the x,y, of them.

```
mu1 = [1 2]; Sigma1 = [2 0; 0 0.5];
mu2 = [-3 -5]; Sigma2 = [1 0;0 1];
X = [mvnrnd(mu1,Sigma1,1000); mvnrnd(mu2,Sigma2,1000)];
GMModel = fitgmdist(X,2);
figure
y = [zeros(1000,1);ones(1000,1)];
h = gscatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),y);
hold on
gmPDF = @(x,y) arrayfun(@(x0,y0) pdf(GMModel,[x0 y0]),x,y);
g = gca;
fcontour(gmPDF,[g.XLim g.YLim])
title('{\bf Scatter Plot and Fitted Gaussian Mixture Contours}')
legend(h,'Model 0','Model1')
hold off
```

So, in the following figure, I'd like to to be able to plot the 99% in dashed black line "k". Any idea how to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try specifying the 'LevelList' property? something like `fcontour(gmPDF, '--k', 'LevelList', [0.99])`?

Comment: thanks! it does show only that levellist, but the output coordinates (gmPDF.XData, gmPDF.YData, gmPDF.ZData) have ALL the contour lines... :/

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What does it mean that output coordinates have all the contour lines? `gmPDF` is a function handle isn't it? So `fcontour(gmPDF, '--k', 'LevelList', [0.99])` will display the contour line where your function will have the value 0.99, regardless of your "output coordinates"

Comment: correct, it only displays the levellist inputted. But when you get the coordinates outputted in the handle, there are a bunch of levels, not just the one inputted.

Comment: Ah, you don't want to just display it, but you also want the position of the contour line?

Comment: that did the trick! thanks a lot @MatteoV!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display and get the coordinates of the given contour line specifying the LevelList property of `fcontour`, and then reading the ContourMatrix property of the contour handle:

```
% Random function, insert here yours
f = @(x,y) arrayfun(@(x0,y0) x0.^2 + y0.^2 - 0.1,x,y);

% The function value you want to get the contour for
lvl = 0.99;

% Plot the contour line
cHandle = fcontour(f, '--k', 'LevelList', [lvl]);
hold on

% Get the coordinates
lvlX = cHandle.ContourMatrix(1, 2:end);
lvlY = cHandle.ContourMatrix(2, 2:end);

% For a check:
plot(lvlX, lvlY, '--r')
```

Comment: Is there a similar answer of this problem in python?